# Fail to select the FROM date correctly in MYSQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

```
  $from = "2017-7-1";
  $to = "2017-8-25";
```

I don't know why i cant seems to select the **from date** in the **HTML5 date picker** correctly, for instance when i pick 2017-7-1, the result page wont show the result data on 2017-7-1 ,
but when i pick 2017-6-30 which is **ONE day BEFORE**, it can show.
Any idea why?
I have tried both the BETWEEN CLause and the >= AND <=,
They both dont work
Any idea why? Thanks

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail WHERE nextdate BETWEEN 
  '$from' AND '$to'");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail WHERE nextdate >= 
  '$from' AND nextdate <= '$to'");
```

Comment: updated and have tried, still no luck, any idea

Comment: which data type is nextdate ?

Comment: Why do you have mysql .... first use mysqli and pass the connection variable in first parameter

Comment: Did you check whether you get correct data in your `from` and `to` vars? If yes, then try to use `to_date` function for your vars. Like `... to_date ('$from', 'YYYY-MM-DD')...` .

Comment: @scaisEdge it is varchar.  Farsay sorry abt the confusion, i k mysql is deprecated, but as a newbie, wanna keep things a liitle bit simpler, so i use mysql

Comment: @Ikrom , i have tried to use echo and it's the correct data, and  to_date() dont seems to work

Comment: Then also use `to_date` function for your `nextdate` column (cause it varchar) in the script like: `... to_date (nextdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')...` . Or check for `str_to_date` function in mysql. Your problem is with converting string to date.

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated mysql api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert properly to date

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM treatmentdetail 
   WHERE str_to_date(nextdate, '%Y-%m-%d') 
      BETWEEN str_to_date('$from','%Y-%m-%d' ) AND  str_to_date('$to','%Y-%m-%d' )
```

*and you should use most recent mysql driver .. with param binding too*

Comment: THank you, Works like a charm, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing connection variable
I think you will have to use connection variable.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail WHERE nextdate BETWEEN 
  '$from' AND '$to'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your field to DATE and 
save your date as YYYY-MM-DD like in you example

```
  $from = "2017-07-01";
  $to = "2017-08-25";
```

You can do then your search correctly with mysql(i)

```
SELECT * FROM treatmentdetail 
    WHERE 
        nextdate >= '$from' AND nextdate <= '$to';
```

Have a look on the docs

[MySQL DATATYPES DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)